# Can't Update ProgressBar in GridView in an AppWidget

Tags: android, gridview, android-appwidget, android-remoteview

I am working on AppWidget for Android. I have a GridView on AppWidget and in every single item of GridView i Have a ProgressBarr. This ProgressBar should be updated Live(as i want to see it progressing from left to right). Unfortunately my code " a thread " is doing it but not accurately . when i scroll down or scroll up i can see change, otherwise everything is just like stopped on the widget. I Have tried to update widget in the Thread it is working . i can see live progress but i got another problem here . Problem is that every single item is expanding on Whole screen and iterating one by one and showing Progress on ProgressBar. I have commented in the Code where i have updated widget and got problem. Please any Help ? I will thankful to you.

This is the screen shot when I drag my widget on home screen then I can see my GridView..

[image]

Then cause of that updateWidget call my widget looks like this . it is updating progress bar but I don't want like this . It should be update in the progressBarr as shown above . instead of doing in those gridview items it is expanding items on widget then start iterating items on the widget and also keep updating.
[image]
[image]

these are two different items.

My Code is.

```
public class ListProvider implements RemoteViewsFactory {
private ArrayList<ListItem> listItemList = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
private Context context = null;
private int appWidgetId;
private int mProgressStatus = 0;
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager ;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();


public ListProvider(Context context, Intent intent,
        ArrayList<ListItem> listItems) {
    this.context = context;

    appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
            AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    if (listItems != null)
        this.listItemList = (ArrayList<ListItem>) listItems.clone();

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listItemList.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

/*
 * Similar to getView of Adapter where instead of View return RemoteViews
 * And using the saved ImagePath to show images on ImageView
 */
@Override
public RemoteViews getViewAt(final int position) {
    final RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(
            context.getPackageName(), R.layout.list_row);
    final ListItem listItem = listItemList.get(position);
    remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.heading, (listItem.heading).toUpperCase());

    remoteView.setViewVisibility(R.id.ProgressTime, View.VISIBLE);
    remoteView.setProgressBar(R.id.ProgressTime, 100, mProgressStatus, false);


    Thread worker = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mProgressStatus=0;
            while(mProgressStatus<100){
                mProgressStatus = mProgressStatus+3;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2011);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        remoteView.setProgressBar(R.id.ProgressTime, 100, mProgressStatus, false);

                    }
                });

                /////  I have tried doing this ... this solution did work for me but 
                //    this  is expanding one item on whole widget and showing only 
                //    one item on AppWidget instead of showing all GridView
                //    i know this is not gona work properly for me . i Need something else
                ///  tell me from where i should do this call so i can see all gridview at same time 
                //   and can see live update.

                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteView);
            }



        }
    });
    worker.start();


    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(listItem.fileUrl);
    if (bitmap != null)
        remoteView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView, bitmap);

    else
        remoteView.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageView, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    return remoteView;
}
@Override
public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

}

@Override
public void onDataSetChanged() {
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
}

}
```

Comment: Hey, have you find answer?

Comment: Dear use a thread inside the adapter and keep it running then start updating progressbar in that thread .. .

Comment: I have a gridview in appwidget. In this GirdView is not update.

Comment: do you know how to update it?..Please help me.

Comment: I wish I can help You. But I haven't work much on widgets. It was a lame try from my side. then I never worked on this.

Comment: Ok..Thank you for reply..